# What are the benefits/drawbacks to serializing a class in a fully serializable hierarchy, vs. Serializable child of non-serializable ancestry?

Tags: java, serialization

That is

(1)

```
class A 
B extends A
C extends B
D extends C 
E extends D implements Serializable
```

vs.

(2)

```
A implements Serializable
B extends A
C extends B
D extends C 
E extends D
```

(1)In the first case, serializing E will result in the state of E being saved, and A through D being reconstructed upon deserialization through a call to D's default constructor.

(2)In the second case, serializing E will result in the state of A through E all being saved, and no reconstruction required upon deserialization (since everything would be seriailizable due to inheriting from a serializable base class.)

Are there any dangers to doing it the first way?  Would there be circumstances in which the savings of data transferred during serialization/deserialization by doing it the first way would be sufficient to make it a preferred approach, or is it always best to fully serialize the class hierarchy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "reconstructed" here? Do you mean there's code in E to *explicitly* remember the pieces of A-D state which are required?

Comment: Given that A<-B<-C<-D<-E, and A,B,C,D are not serializable, when E was deserialized, it would trigger a call to the default constructor of D (the nearest non-serializable parent) just to restore the object of type E.  Because the parent levels couldn't be serialized, the JVM must call their constructors (much like the chain of one or more super() calls needed to set up any subclass object) to restore the entire object state of E (including state of superclasses,) even though E itself was serialized.  

I am referring to that process.

Comment: So "Are there any dangers to doing it the first way" is pretty clearly "You're losing huge amounts of information" - if you're only calling the parameterless constructors, then any information only in the superclasses is lost, which would make me suspect that the inheritance hierarchy was badly designed to start with, in most cases. Heck, this approach only even works if there are parameterless constructors all the way up, as far as I can tell. (I'd avoid Java's binary serialization scheme anyway, to be honest, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Depending on the frameworks that are being used, it may be impossible to avoid Serializable.  In Java EE 5+, for example, any time a method call on a session bean is performed and that call could be remote, then Serializable is required.  Also Serializable is codified into the contract of JavaBeans.  It's better to know (and respect) the advantages and limitations of Serializable than it is to recommend avoiding it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It is not usually considered a best practice to implement `Serializable` in a superclass, particularly if it is intended as a base class in a hierarchy of an exported API (however, your base class **should** be designed to anticipate subclasses that implement Serializable; see below).  The reason is that it forces the clients of your API to make their subclasses serializable whether or not it useful for them to do so (Essential Java, 2nd Ed).

The exception to this rule is when the base class itself participates in a framework for which `Serializable` is necessary.

Regardless, there are problems that can arise if a subclass is serializable and its parent isn't.  In such a case the subclass is responsible for serializing and deserializing the state of its parent.  The drawbacks are:

- the parent fields can not be `final`
- if the parent fields are not accessible to the subclass, then a correct serialized representation may not be possible
- parent classes that don't implement `Serializable` themselves require no-arg constructors

There is an excellent discussion of the pitfalls and recommended practices of serializing Java instances in Essential Java, 2nd Ed.